Vertically center a cell with nicematrix
I would to know how to center vertically the cells 2-2(c) and 2-3 (d) in the following example
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{ccc}[hvlines,cell-space-limits=10pt]
  & \Block{1-2}{a} \\
  \Block{}{\rotate bbbb} & c & d \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}

The key v-center or m does not work (Package nicematrix Error: The key 'v-center' is unknown for the command \Block).

You should use directly the command \rotate with its key  c. There is no point using a command \Block in your case and (that's why nicematrix has a rather strange behavior with your code...).
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{ccc}[hvlines,cell-space-limits=10pt]
  & \Block{1-2}{a} \\
  \rotate[c] bbbb & c & d \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}



It does not work for me. I have [c] bbbb in cell 2-1 and the cells 2-2 and 2-3 are not vertically center.

You probably don't have the latest version of nicematrix. You should try update your TeX distribution (TeXLive, MiKTeX, etc.). If you use Overleaf, Overleaf has not the latest version of nicematrix. You should upload the latest version of the file nicematrix.sty in the repertory of your Overleaf project. You can find that file on the SVN server of TeXLive: www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nicematrix/nicematrix.sty
